# Virtualization-enabled dual-boot linux with universal access to data folder/partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, multi-boot

**My situation:** I want to setup my work laptop as a Windows + Linux dual-booting system (probably Windows 7 and Ubuntu) with the possibility of running the Linux installation as a virtual machine from Windows (probably through VirtualBox). As I have read for instance [here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/359980/run-a-dual-boot-operative-system-virtually), this should not be too difficult. This appeals to me because it would allow me to run Linux at full performance when I need while also allowing me to use it for less performance-critical tasks from within Windows.

In this setup I would like to have a data folder (either a folder on the Windows partition or a separate partition) that can be easily accessed from both Windows and Linux, and regardless if Linux is run as a virtual machine or not. But when Linux is run as a virtual machine it cannot mount any partitions already mounted by Windows.

**How can I ...**

1. ... get Linux to automatically mount a partition when booted non-virtually but instead access the same partition via a "shared folder" when booted as a virtual machine?
2. ... make it so that this folder/partition is accessed from the same path in Linux regardless of whether it is accessed as a "shared folder" in the virtual machine or as a mounted partition non-virtually.

**Also:**

3. Are there any clear advantages to using a separate partition for the shared data as opposed to using a folder on the Windows partition? Any advantages in addition to those gained by having a separate data partition on a normal single-boot system? If so, what would be an appropriate file system to use for the data partition?
4. Is this a terrible idea for some reason?

Comment: I've got the same problem, with an added wrinkle: It's not reasonable (in my case) to move shared data onto the Windows system partition because I've got the Windows (and Linux, Mint in my case) OS partitions on an SSD and there just isn't the space.

Comment: My best guess would be to remove the data partition from Linux's `/etc/fstab` entirely (whether loaded from the drive or from a shared folder) and instead include a script that somehow detects what it's running as, that runs on startup. I'm not sure how to detect that, though, and would guess that it's probably provably impossible to guarantee accurate detection of virtualization.