# Detect whether running in VM and mount differently depending on that

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, mount, hardware-detection, auto-detect

Context: I am a second person who had [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1047879/virtualization-enabled-dual-boot-linux-with-universal-access-to-data-folder-part) - a dual-boot system with a shared data partition, plus wanting to run one of the OSs in a VM on the other. Thinking on it, I realized that it could potentially be solved by moving the disk-mount out of `/etc/fstab` and into a separate startup script that mounts the data partition either directly from the drive or from a folder shared by the VM software, depending on whether the system is running in a VM or not. Either way to the same place in the filesystem.

I would prefer a method which can have three states: "Running in VM", "Running outside VM", and "can't tell." That way, if it was running in the VM, but the VM software was misconfigured so the shared folder doesn't appear to the virtualized OS (has happened to me before), it doesn't try to mount the actual drive and break everything. Unfortunately, that counts out the only idea I had, which was "check for the shared folder, and if it's not there, assume not a VM."

So, how can this be done? Preferably without needing me to mount it manually every time I boot.

If relevant, one OS is Windows 10 and the other is Linux Mint, and Mint would be the one that's in a VM (sometimes).

Comment: What about having your script check for the MAC address of the currently enabled NIC? Hardware MAC = running outside VM, virual MAC = running inside VM and other MAC = unknown. Unless you have a non-trivial NIC setup this should not be too hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, *any* Linux, running in a VM environment is signalled by the presence of a **hypervisor** flag in */proc/cpuinfo*. So, running an Arch Linux guest inside a Debian host, I get (as *sudo*!):

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 61
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 4
cpu MHz     : 2394.460
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 20
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc xtopology nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch rdseed
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4790.45
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Sometimes, people will use a script called *virt-what* (available in most repos) to do this, but this is more hassle than it is worth in your case; also, it requires installing extra software (*virt-what* and *dmidecode* if this this does not ship by default with your distro, as is the case for instance with Arch Linux).

Comment: Are there plausible situations where that flag fails to appear, assuming no intensional attempt to disguise the VM as hardware?

Comment: @DavidHeyman None, unless you are thinking of Linux containers which are not really VMs, hence no *hypervisor* flag.

Comment: No, I was just thinking of misconfiguration.